# R: Problems while plotting sampled values from a curve

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to simulate a signal in order to apply some methods of non-linear fittings, but I have some problems when plotting it.

```
x<-sample(seq(0,1,length.out = 1000),200)
y<-2*sin(4*pi*x)-6*abs(x-0.4)^(0.3)+2*exp(-30*(4*x-2)^2)+8*x+rnorm(200,0,0.5)
s<-2*sin(4*pi*x)-6*abs(x-0.4)^(0.3)+2*exp(-30*(4*x-2)^2)+8*x
plot(x,y)
lines(x,s,col="red")
```

The idea I want to have 200 observations uniformly sampled with an additive white noise term, and the I would like to plot this "perturbed" signal together with the original signal. (y and s respectively).
The fact is that if I use the code that I wrote I obtain as result something like:

[image]

Probably is such a simple thing, but I'm kinda stuck with this.

Any hint or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines are plotted sequentially, and you decided to randomly draw your X values, so x values sitting next to each other in `x` are not next to each other on the axis - hence the mess. Just sort it:

```
x<-sort(sample(seq(0,1,length.out = 1000),200))
y<-2*sin(4*pi*x)-6*abs(x-0.4)^(0.3)+2*exp(-30*(4*x-2)^2)+8*x+rnorm(200,0,0.5)
s<-2*sin(4*pi*x)-6*abs(x-0.4)^(0.3)+2*exp(-30*(4*x-2)^2)+8*x
plot(x,y)
lines(x,s,col="red")
```

Another way to do this on the fly mentioned by mickey is:

```
ord = order(x)
lines(x[ord], s[ord], col = 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: Very clear, I thought R automatically ordered observations. Thanks

Comment: Additionally, if `x`, `y`, and `s` are fixed, you can do `ord = order(x); lines(x[ord], s[ord], col = 'red')`

Comment: I'll accept the answer as soon as the site allows me

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorder the x observations order in ascending order, you can do that by storing everything in a dataframe object and then ordering it:

```
x<-sample(seq(0,1,length.out = 1000),200)
df_p= data.frame(x)
df_p$y<-2*sin(4*pi*df_p$x)-6*abs(df_p$x-0.4)^(0.3)+2*exp(-30*(4*df_p$x-2)^2)+8*df_p$x+rnorm(200,0,0.5)
df_p$s<-2*sin(4*pi*df_p$x)-6*abs(df_p$x-0.4)^(0.3)+2*exp(-30*(4*df_p$x-2)^2)+8*df_p$x

df_p = df_p[order(df_p$x),]

plot(df_p$x,df_p$y)
lines(df_p$x, df_p$s,col="red")
```

Also if you want to avoid this step you can use the ggplot2 library:

```
p <- ggplot(df_p) + geom_point(aes(x = x,y= y)) + geom_line(aes(x=x,y=s,color='red'))
plot(p)
```